# Does not golang has same method of tobytes() in Python PIL

Tags: image, go, pixel

Now, I have problem of extracting pixel bytes from image by using GO.

I know there is tobytes() method in Python PIL.

this is [PIL DOC](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.tobytes)

```py
from PIL import Image

m = Image.open("123123.png")
bytes = im.tobytes()
```

However, I have no idea for searching the similar method in GO.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `png.Encode`?

```
buff := new(bytes.Buffer)
err := png.Encode(buff, img)
imgBytes := buff.Bytes()
```

more information can be found [here](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/go1.17.1:src/image/png/writer.go;l=566)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).